# MVC Core Repository Pattern for Multiple Lookup tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have  Customer transactional table with multiple lookup tables with foreign keys. We want to create dropdown menus using these lookup tables, when CustomerService creates a Customer order transaction. If a person views the transactions later, they would see the 4 tables joined together.

Would I create,

(a) 4 interfaces with 4 repositories,

(b) or 2 interfaces (1 for Customer Transaction, 1 interface for the lookup tables), with 1 Repository for Customer Transaction, and 3 repositories for lookup table interface?

We want to relay Lookup table Repository to the SelectList below. Each select list is picking certain columns. Want to be efficient in code.

**Models:**

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId{ get; set; },
    public int ProductTypeId {get; set; }, //joins to ProductTypeTable
    public int StatusKey {get; set; },  //joins to StatusTypeTable
    public int CustomerTypeId {get; set; } //joins to CustomerTypeTable
    public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; },
    public string PurchaseAmount { get; set; },
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId{ get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; },
    public string ProductName { get; set; },
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; },
}

public class StatusType
{
    public int StatusKey{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; },
    public string Symbol { get; set; },
}

public class CustomerType
{
    public int KeyNumber{ get; set; },
    public int Height{ get; set; }
    public string HairColor{ get; set; },
    public string NameOfPerson{ get; set; },
    public string ResearchNotes{ get; set; },
}
```

Required fieldsin dropdown

```
ViewData["ProductTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductType, "ProductName", "ProductDescription");

ViewData["KeyNumber"] = new SelectList(_context.CustomerType , "NameofPerson", "Description");

ViewData["StatusKey"] = new SelectList(_context.StatusType, "Symbol", "ResearchNotes");
```

Comment: Depends.  Single app, soup to nuts?  Or server-side (Web API) and client-side (MVC/Razor/Angular/whatever)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) that supplies what your front end needs.

```
public class EditTransaction {
    CustomerTransaction customerTransaction { get; set; }
    SelectList productTypes { get; set; }
    SelectList statusType { get; set; }
    SelectList customerTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Include a class/method/controller/whatever that accesses your DAL repositories and assembles the DTO.  Your client-side code picks up the DTO.  Nothing "special" in the repositories nor the UI.